# how to calculate from each row value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named general_ledger from which I need to show dr_amount, cr_amount and the balance between them as running_balance. That's why I have written a query that is given below. But I am getting the result of each query like the balance only of current row. But I need to produce the result with the remaining balance. Suppose First row dr_balance is 20000 and cr_balance is 5000 and remaining balance is 15000. In second row only cr_balance is 5000. Now the result should be 10000 with the deduction but my result is -5000. I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone please help me on this? I need your help very much. Here is my query given below :

```
    SELECT                    '' AS cost_center_id
                                        , '' AS cost_center_name
                                        , '' AS office_code
                                        , CONVERT('2013-02-01',DATETIME) AS transaction_date
                                        , '' AS accounts_head_id
                                        , '' AS account_name
                                        , '' AS opposite_accounts_head_id
                                        , '' AS opposite_account_name
                                        , 'Opening Balance' AS particulars
                                        , tempOpeningBalance.dr_amount
                                        , tempOpeningBalance.cr_amount
                                        , '' AS voucher_no
                                        , '' AS vin
                                        FROM (SELECT IFNULL(mcoa.account_code,'1101010101100321') AS account_code
                                                , IFNULL(mcoa.account_name,'Cash') AS account_name
                                                , IFNULL(mcoa.account_type,'ASSET') AS accountType
                                                , CAST(IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(maingl.dr_balance,0)),0) AS DECIMAL(27,5)) AS dr_amount
                                                , CAST(IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(maingl.cr_balance,0)),0) AS DECIMAL(27,5)) AS cr_amount
                                                FROM master_chart_of_accounts AS mcoa
                                                INNER JOIN chart_of_accounts AS coa ON (mcoa.id = coa.master_chart_of_accounts_id AND mcoa.id = 80)
                                                LEFT JOIN general_ledger AS maingl ON (coa.id = maingl.accounts_head_id AND coa.account_code='1101010101100321')
                                                INNER JOIN
                                                (   SELECT  gl.accounts_head_id, MAX(gl.gl_id) AS max_gl_id, gl.office_code, gl.office_type, gl.country_id,gl.cost_center_id
                                                       FROM     general_ledger AS gl
                            -- INNER JOIN voucher_info AS vi ON (gl.voucher_info_id = vi.id)
                                                        -- WHERE  vi.posting_date < '2013-02-01' AND
                                                        WHERE gl.transaction_date < '2013-02-01' AND
                                                          gl.cost_center_id IN ('BI0000000000000000000001') AND
                                                          gl.country_id IN (1) AND
                                                          gl.office_code IN ('UG500013') AND
                                                          1=1
                                                GROUP BY gl.accounts_head_id, gl.office_code, gl.office_type, gl.country_id,gl.cost_center_id
                                                ORDER BY gl.accounts_head_id
                                                ) AS tmpgl
                                                ON (    maingl.office_code = tmpgl.office_code
                                                AND maingl.office_type = tmpgl.office_type
                                                AND maingl.accounts_head_id = tmpgl.accounts_head_id
                                                AND maingl.country_id = tmpgl.country_id
                                                AND maingl.cost_center_id = tmpgl.cost_center_id
                                                AND maingl.gl_id = tmpgl.max_gl_id
                                                   )
                                                 WHERE  mcoa.account_status_id = 1 AND
                                                    coa.account_status_id = 1
                                             ) AS tempOpeningBalance

UNION

SELECT      vi.cost_center_id
      , cc.center_name AS cost_center_name
      , gl.office_code
      , vi.posting_date AS transaction_date
      , vd.accounts_head_id
      , (SELECT chart_of_accounts.account_name FROM chart_of_accounts WHERE chart_of_accounts.id = vd.accounts_head_id) AS account_name
      , vd.opposite_accounts_head_id
      , (SELECT chart_of_accounts.account_name FROM chart_of_accounts WHERE chart_of_accounts.id = vd.opposite_accounts_head_id) AS opposite_account_name
      , vd.particulars
      , gl.dr_amount AS dr_amount -- here to check
      , gl.cr_amount AS cr_amount
      , vi.voucher_no
      , vi.vin
FROM general_ledger AS gl
INNER JOIN voucher_info AS vi
 ON (gl.voucher_info_id = vi.id)
INNER JOIN cost_center AS cc
 ON (vi.cost_center_id = cc.id)
INNER JOIN voucher_details AS vd
 ON (vi.id = vd.voucher_info_id)
INNER JOIN chart_of_accounts AS coa
 ON (vd.accounts_head_id = coa.id)

WHERE   vi.posting_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND'2013-02-28'
    AND vi.voucher_status_id = 3
    AND vd.status_id = 1
    AND vi.office_code = 'UG500063'
    AND coa.account_code='1101010101100321'
    AND coa.cost_center_id = 'BI0000000000000000000001'
ORDER BY   cost_center_name
     , office_code
     , transaction_date;
```

Comment: In my humble opinion the table itself should be storing such kind of values. For example in your case, for row 1: dr_balance: 20000, cr_balance: 5000, the remaining balance 15000 should be the dr_amount of row 2. In that case your query will return the expected result. Otherwise you have to write procedure to achieve this. Also, if possible try to paste your sample table data here that might give a clear idea.

Comment: @learningloop I gave given a sample of my table in the way the data has inserted. Can it will be helpfull?!

Comment: The answer by user Ravindra is more apt and works.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable like this

```
SET @running_balance=0;
SELECT dr_amount AS dr_amount 
      , cr_amount AS cr_amount
      , @running_balance := (@running_balance + dr_amount - cr_amount)
FROM general_ledger
```

Comment: thanks for your answers. But my query is a complex query. Actually I am giving the full query. I am using it for reporting. it is a long query. But I am extremely expecting your help on this. Here I am editing my query.

Comment: Instead of directly doing a `union`, select opening balance related data into a temp table and then using that temp table calculate your running balance. My approach is to handle the running balance in the report itself.

Comment: I also thought so. But I have no idea how to do it in i-report. That's why I am struggling it in sql

Comment: hey everybody, I have solved the problem in i-report. thank you so much for your concentration.